# Why didn't Snape reappear when Harry used the Resurrection Stone?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

If I were Harry I'd want to thank Snape or at least get some kind of closure..

Comment: Given that he was going to his death, I doubt thanking Snape was on his mind at the time. Also, I'm not sure how much of the decision about who was brought back was conscious. That passage of the book is vaguer than I'd like.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Harry basically went straight to the forest from the Penseive with all this new information swimming around in his head about Snape. On one hand, he probably *wanted* to process more fully what he had seen in the Pensieve. On the other hand, he didn't have time to reflect. So I think it would have been impossible for Harry to have fully processed all the information about Snape within the minutes that elapsed between the Pensieve and the Resurrection Stone scene.

Snape was not one of Harry's "loved ones" at that moment; I don't think Snape's presence would have facilitated Harry accomplishing his mission at that point.

Frankly, I don't think Snape would have wanted to be there anyway. Having Snape and Lily together in ghost form would be awkward. The idea of hanging out in spectral form with James, Remus, and Sirius would probably make Snape wish he were alive once more, solely to die again in protest. And really, Snape didn't like Harry; he did what he did for Lily. One of the memories Harry saw in the Pensieve is Snape begging Dumbledore to save Lily -- only Lily -- to which Dumbledore said, "You disgust me." At least at one point, Harry knows that Snape considered Harry's life expendable.

Harry obviously came to regard Snape in high esteem, but I wager it took a long time and a lot of thought.

Answer (score 0):

Just because Snape had been noble didn't mean they were friends. And anyway, Harry didn't want closure so much as strength and encouragement.